# Как добавить в массив уникальную дату из другого массива?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив с датами, хочу перенести из обычного массива в объект массив. Но нужно что бы в объект записывались только уникальные даты без дубляжа.
Запутался совсем, не соображу что нужно сделать.

```js
let namesId = ["Вторник 17.08", "Среда 11.07", "Понедельник 17.08", "Суббота 23.09", "Среда 11.07", "Четверг 01.12", "Пятница 11.07", "Вторник 17.08", "Четверг 01.12", ];

function listKeyboard(keyBoard) {

    keyBoard = {
        "inline_keyboard": []
    };

    for (let i = 0; i < namesId.length; i++) {

        keyBoard.inline_keyboard[i] = [{
            "text": namesId[i],
            'callback_data': i
        }];

    }

    return keyBoard;

}
console.log(listKeyboard());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить уникальные можно через `new Set()`.

```js
const namesId = ["Вторник 17.08", "Среда 11.07", "Понедельник 17.08", "Суббота 23.09", "Среда 11.07", "Четверг 01.12", "Пятница 11.07", "Вторник 17.08", "Четверг 01.12", ];
const keyBoard = {
  inline_keyboard: [...new Set(namesId)].map((item, index) => ({
    text: item,
    callback_data: index
  }))
};
console.log(keyBoard);
```

Через `for` в функции.

```js
const namesId = ["Вторник 17.08", "Среда 11.07", "Понедельник 17.08", "Суббота 23.09", "Среда 11.07", "Четверг 01.12", "Пятница 11.07", "Вторник 17.08", "Четверг 01.12", ];
const uniqueNamesId = [...new Set(namesId)];

function listKeyboard(keyBoard) {
    keyBoard = {
        "inline_keyboard": []
    };
    for (let index = 0; index < uniqueNamesId.length; index++) {
        keyBoard.inline_keyboard.push({
            text: uniqueNamesId[index],
            callback_data: index
        });
    }
    return keyBoard;
};
console.log(listKeyboard());
```

Comment: в `map` ж индекс приходит, зачем `reduce`

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov кстати да, перепишу на `map`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Теперь понял. Но как сделать именно через цикл, как в моей конструкции. Мне нужно именно с помощью  for (let i = 0; i < namesId.length; i++) .  Просто беру данные из гугл таблицы, и с помощью цикла for я манипулирую данными для разных категорий.  Если есть у Вас желание дайте пожалуйста пример, как сделать все в цикле, что бы я мог сохранить мой изначальный шаблон

Comment: @Дмитрий добавил. Конечно бы ваш код отрефакторить. Например в функцию передаётся параметр, который тут же переопределяется. Также внутри функции читаются данные снаружи, а хорошо бы их передать в виде параметра внутрь функции. В общем можно сделать красиво.

Comment: если это психологический шаблон, то полезно бы его пересмотреть, и пробовать программировать по-разному, особенно если по-другому короче и надежней.

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov reduce работает в два раза быстрее, чем map, но читается сложнее, хотя в данном вопросе это конечно же незаметно. Замеры - https://jsfiddle.net/p609o7xt/

Comment: @renich, это я про шаблон Дмитрия с `for(;;)`... Да map легче читается, меньше мест, где можно ошибиться. И, по-моему, это важнее до тех пор, пока разница не заметна.

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov ясно. А у меня просто срабатывает сишная привычка оптимизации по скорости работы даже на таких мелочах.